# Wordpress mysql password hash

Tags: mysql, wordpress

What is the best/easiest way to hash Wordpress db mysql password ?

/** MySQL database password */

define('DB_PASSWORD', 'mypassword');

How to hash "mypassword" ?

I have tried md5 and SHA1 but not worked, only plain unencrypted text work.

Comment: To hash it? You mean so you don't have the plain text in your wp-config file? You can't: it needs the real password so that it can connect to the database. The database may store the password hashed at its end, but it needs to be in clear here. It's not for comparison against a user-entered password, which are the ones you hash.

Comment: Yes to hash it, I have plan text now and I want to hash it, while wordpress installation it's not normal password in text

Comment: And in your mind, how is the password hash supposed to help you?

Comment: The problem is that WordPress can't log into the database without the normal password in text, and it can't recover the password from the hash. The best you could do is add an encryption or obfuscation algorithm to WordPress then store your password encrypted/obfuscated, but since WordPress necessarily needs to decrypt it so that it can connect to the database you'll need to leave the decode mechanism and keys on disk too. And so any attacker who can read your files will be able to steal that too.

Comment: Thank you very much  guys for your answers, obfuscation is not the good and very secure way and not secure indeed. Really nonsense, file permissions all other issues are more important to protect this file, sorry for confusion I fully understand it now.

Answer (score 2):

Like @Rup said, you need the plaintext password to your WordPress database to be available in your php code. That's because the connect request from php to MySQL needs it to be in plaintext.

It would be nice if you could conceal it with a hash somehow, but unfortunately that's not how authentication to the MySQL DBMS works.

Most people create a custom MySQL credential pair (username/password) for each WordPress installation, and restrict access for that credential pair to just the database for that instance. That limits the damage if somebody manages to steal the password.

Notice that the WordPress security programmers are very smart indeed, and they've been working on it for over ten years now. In those ten years, various WP installations have come under countless cracking attempts. Even if you're an extremely competent and security-aware programmer yourself, you'd be very wise to use their code, because they've had a chance to debug it in the real world.